# How to avoid concurrency on aggregates status using Rebus in a server cluster

Tags: domain-driven-design, servicebus, rebus

I have a web service that use Rebus as Service Bus. 
Rebus is configured as explained in [this post](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/4008).
The web service is load balanced with a two servers cluster.

These services are for a production environment and each production machine sends commands to save the produced quantities and/or to update its state.
In the BL I've modelled an Aggregate Root for each machine and it executes the commands emitted by the real machine. To preserve the correct status, the Aggregate needs to receive the commands in the same sequence as they were emitted, and, since there is no concurrency for that machine, that is the same order they are saved on the bus.

E.G.: the machine XX sends a command of *'add new piece done'* and then the command *'Set stop for maintenance'*. Executing these commands in a sequence you should have Aggregate XX in state *'Stop'*, but, with multiple server/worker roles, you could have that both commands are executed at the same time on the same version of Aggregate. This means that, depending on who saves the aggregate first, I can have Aggregate XX with state *'Stop'* or *'Producing pieces'* ... that is not the same thing.

I've introduced a Service Bus to add scale out as the number of machine scales and resilience (if a server fails I have only slowdown in processing commands).

Actually I'm using the name of the aggregate like a "*topic*" or "*destinationAddress*" with the ***IAdvancedApi***, so the name of the aggregate is saved into the **recipient** of the transport. Then I've created a custom Transport class that:
 1. does not remove the messages in progress but sets them in state
    *InProgress*.
 2. to retrive the messages selects only those that are in a *recipient* that have no one *InProgress*.

I'm wandering: is this the best way to guarantee that the bus executes the commands for aggregate in the same sequence as they arrived?

Comment: Aren't you asking too much from Rebus? I.e. trying to turn a lightweight messaging solution into a high availability and ordering-guarantee  powerhouse?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be have some kind of locking of your aggregate root, which needs to happen at the data store level.

E.g. by using optimistic locking (probably implemented with some kind of revision number or something like that), you would be sure that you would never accidentally overwrite another node's edits.

This would allow for your aggregate to either

a) accept the changes in either order (which is generally preferable – makes your system more tolerant), or
b) reject an invalid change

If the aggregate rejects the change, this could be implemented by throwing an exception. And then, in the Rebus handler that catches this exception, you can e.g. `await bus.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), theMessage)` which will cause it to be delivered again in five seconds.

Comment: At the moment I have implemented a custom Transport: 1) On Receive messages are not delete but set in a "InProgress" status and removed only on context.OnCompleted/OnAborted. 2) when selecting a message to send I look for messages that have no one with the same recipient "InProgress".

Comment: I thought about lock the aggregate but I don't like the idea of the bus spending time on trying to execute messages that he can not execute at that time. That's why I moved the semaphore at the transport level.

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on message order in a service bus / queuing / messaging environment.

When you *do* find yourself in this position you may need to re-think your design.  Firstly, a service bus is most certainly *not* an event store and attempting to use it like one is going to lead to pain and suffering :) --- not that you are attempting this but I thought I'd throw it in there.

As for your design, in order to manage this kind of state you may want to look at a process manager.  If you are not generating those commands then even this will not help.

However, given your scenario it seems as though the calls are sequential but perhaps it is just your example.  In any event, as mookid8000 said, you either want to:

- discard invalid changes (with the appropriate feedback),
- allow any order of messages as long as they are valid,
- ignore out-of-sequence messages till later.

Hope that helps...

Comment: In my scenario the calls for a specific aggregate are absolutely sequential and I must guarantee that are executed in the same order.

Comment: The easiest would probably be to keep the sequence number on the message (as mookid mentioned with the revision number).  Then it is a matter of ignoring a message that does not follow on from the ARs registered sequence number...

Comment: I did something similar (please read the comment to Moonkid's answer): in my case a reliable sequence is arrival position in the queue and I do not consume messages for that AR where there is another for it in progress. I was wandering if there is a more "Rebus oriented" approach.

Comment: *"You should never rely on message order"* - can you explain why you make this a general statement? Some systems like RabbitMQ do guarantee ordering depending on your setup. The AMQP protocol spec has a paragraph about the conditions under which ordering is guaranteed.

Comment: @guillaume31: I guess the short answer would be that it is just going to be less painful if you can get away without having ordered messages since ordered messages are somewhat of a bottleneck.  What happens when processing of a message fails?  All messages following on from that message would have to wait since one would need them ordered.  How about multi-threaded scenarios?  It is rather tricky to get the message processed in order and somewhat diminishes any gains since the message cannot be processed in parallel.  Even worse in a distributed scenario.

Comment: @guillaume31: That being said, I have projections running against my event store where events are processed in a serial/ordered manner *per projection*.  So if I have 3 projections each will run on its own thread processing events in sequence for each projection.  In short, ordered message processing is simply a situation I would suggest one avoids.

Comment: I can see a lot of cases where ordering is required, and having that support in your message bus technology is a good thing. Besides, I don't think you demonstrated that the OP didn't need ordering. You're talking about an event store while he talks about commands. Right now, a lot of people will pick up your first sentence and stop there, taking it as universal truth, but it's a lot more complicated than that.

Comment: *"All messages following on from that message would have to wait since one would need them ordered."* - wait until what? What does this have to do with ordering?

Comment: If we have message A, B, C, D and B fails we surely cannot continue processing C and D.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You mean, if C and D don't make sense without A and B? Then sure, you cannot continue processing C and D, but you can set them aside and continue with E, F, and so on. There's nothing blocking here, it's not like the consumer will grind to a halt and wait. Wait for what?

Comment: The fact that the messages are expected to be in order seemed to imply that processing would not be able to continue when one fails.  But I really cannot answer that question.  In any event, I'm not too fussed.  If there is a real requirement that you cannot work around then, as I mentioned in the answer, there are ways to implement a solution.

Comment: In my case _stop_ or _producing pieces_ have sense in the any order (because producing ends any stop). So there will be no validation exception. If a command goes in error (not for validation but for unhandled exception) you can go through the others, but then we need compensation actions to align persistance.

Answer (score -1):

> "exactly the same sequence as they were saved on the bus"

Just... why?

Would you rely on your HTTP server logs to know which command actually reached an aggregate first? No because it is totally unreliable, just like it is with at-least-one delivery guarantees and it's also irrelevant.

It is your event store and/or normal persistence state that should be the source of truth when it comes to knowing the sequence of events. The order of commands shouldn't really matter.

Assuming optimistic concurrency, if the aggregate is not allowed to transition from A to C then it should guard this invariant and when a `TransitionToStateC` command will hit it in the `A` state it will simply get rejected.

If on the other hand, `A->C->B` transitions are valid and that is the order received by your aggregate well that is what happened from the domain perspective. It really shouldn't matter which command was published first on the bus, just like it doesn't matter which user executed the command first from the UI.

> "In my scenario the calls for a specific aggregate are absolutely
>   sequential and I must guarantee that are executed in the same order"

Why are you executing them asynchronously and potentially concurrently by publishing on a bus then? What you are basically saying is that calls are sequential and cannot be processed concurrently. That means everything should be synchronous because there is no potential benefit from parallelism.

Why:

```
executeAsync(command1)
executeAsync(command2)
executeAsync(command3)
```

When you want:

```
execute(command1)
execute(command2)
execute(command3)
```

You should have a **single command message** and the handler of this message executes multiple commands against the aggregate. Then again, in this case I'd just create a single operation on the aggregate that performs all the transitions.

Comment: I understand that I've been too generic in the description of the use case. I'll update the description.

Comment: @ilcorvo Why don't you simply model actors instead of relying on an event bus? Every aggregate is single-threaded actor with a mailbox (synchronized message queue). That seems to easily solve your problem. It makes no sense to have competing consumers if you need messages in order.

Comment: I like this idea but how can you suit this with resiliency of the environment in case of server failure? Having 2 servers consuming messages from the same queue I can state that if a 1 server crashes the system can rely on the other one.

Comment: @ilcorvo I'm not sure if what you are trying to achieve is even possible with that level of fault tolerance. With distributed systems you can either be consistent or available, but you cannot be both.